# ServiceStack.Common Support for Windows PHone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, servicestack

I'm planning to develop an app that consume REST services for Windows Phone 7 and came across two excellent framework, [RestSharp](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp) and [ServiceStack](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack). I have no problem in consuming the web services through RestSharp but unable to do so using ServiceStack, primarily because ServiceStack.Common is not supported in WP. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah ServiceStack doesn't officially support Windows Phone 7 yet. There are some community Windows Phone projects of the [ServiceStack JSON/JSV/CSV text serializers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/tree/master/src) but none for [ServiceStack.Common](http://nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Common) project which contains ServiceStack's [C# Service Clients](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/C#-client).

Until ServiceStack releases supported Windows Phone 7 client libraries, your best bet is to use a HTTP + JSON client that supports WP7 like RestSharp.

An alternative is to try the [Windows Phone build of ServiceStack.Text](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/tree/master/src/ServiceStack.Text.WP) and use its [WebRequestExtensions](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/WebRequestExtensions.cs) e.g:

```
var json = "http://myhost/myservice/1".GetJsonFromString();
var dto = json.FromJson<MyResponseDto>();
```

Comment: Understood. I guess I have to try both options and see which one I'm comfortable with. Btw, any plan to release the ServiceStack.Common for WP or WinRT?

Comment: Not WP7, but eventually I would like to have WP8/WinRT C# clients.

Comment: why is there no NuGet package for the SS.Text WP8? tried to make my own build but the pulled project doesn't build :( I've read about your try to do the pcl client but WP8 was not possible, what a shame! still would be great to have at least SS.Text! i'm doing a lot of teaching and workshops for advanced technical colleges, but the WP8 is just a pain (IMHO).-